# Determine convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n=1-2^{\frac{-1}{n}}$, $b_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$.

Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converge or diverge when compared to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ if $p < 1$?

My answer to this is that it diverges, since $b_n$ diverges if $p<1$, and by a comparison test $a_n$ does as well.

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: Note that series for $a_n$ will diverge if the series of $b_n$ diverges, where $b_n$ is less than or equal to $a_n$.

Comment: $a_n\to 1$ so it diverges by the divergence test

Comment: Start by working with $a_n$ = $\:1-2^{-\frac{1}{n}}\:=\:1-\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}$. 

Take the limit of this $a_n$. 

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\:\frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}} = 0$

Divergence test doesn't apply then.

Comment: Presumably, you are asked to *perform* the comparison test. This is the intersting part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p = 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges. Then use the limit comparison test. The limit of the ratios of the terms is $$L = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-2^{-x}}{x}$$

Can you finish from here?

Hint for evaluating that limit:

> Use L'hopital's rule (or the Maclaurin series expansion).

Comment: Or (to find $L$) that $e^x$ is its own derivative, and if $f(x)=2^{-x}=e^{-x\ln2}$ then $L=f'(0).$

Answer (score 1):

If you think it diverges by comparison with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ which diverges, use the limit comparison test to be sure.

The limit comparison test states

$L = \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{a_n}{b_n}$

$=\lim_{n \to 0 }\frac{1-2^{-n}}{n}$

$=\frac{\lim _{n\to 0\:\:}\left(1-2^{-n}\right)}{\lim _{n\to 0\:\:}\left(n\right)}$

$=$undefined

And thus, by limit comparison test, both $a_n$ and $b_n$ diverge. Note that if you evaluate the limit for $n \to \infty$ instead of $n \to 0$ (common error), the limit will be $0$. And again, since $L=0$, diverges. For it to converge, $L$ must be greater than $0$ and less than $\infty$.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to $\sum_nb_n$ with $p<1$ is not useful. What you will find is that $a_n/b_n\to 0,$ but this is not sufficient to decide whether $\sum_na_n$ converges.

Comparing to $\sum_nb_n$ with $p>1$ is not useful either. What you will find is that $a_n/b_n\to \infty,$ but this is  not sufficient to decide whether $\sum_na_n$ converges.

For brevity let $s_n=\frac {\ln 2}{n}.$ When $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $1>s_n>0$ so $$2^{1/n}=\exp (s_n)=1+s_n/1!+s_n^2/2!+... >1+s_n>0.$$ So when $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $2^{-1/n}<1/(1+s_n)$ so $$1-2^{-1/n}>1-1/(1+s_n)=s_n/(1+s_n)>s_n/2=\frac {\ln 2}{2n}.$$ Compare this to $b_n$ with $p=1.$