# How does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverge?

Tags: calculus

Let $a_n=1-2^{\frac{-1}{n}}$, $b_n=\frac{1}{n^p}$.

If $p=1$, then if I want to compare $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$, does it converge or diverge by comparison?

To answer this question, I think it's obvious that $b_n$ diverges, without a doubt. But the real question is am I able to draw this conclusion from comparing it with $b_n$? I know that sometimes these comparison tests do not work, so this is the main problem that i am concerned with.

Comment: Why do you [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067756/determine-convergence-of-sum-n-1-inftya-n) your question?

Comment: @metamorphy these are very different questions! The other one has a different value of p. This one has $p=1$ while the other has $p<1$